# Adding Variable to attr to change background image?

Tags: jquery, variables, background-image, attr

So here is my code But I can't get it to work has anyone got any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

```
function doStuff2() {
      $("#song").css({ 
     'background-image': 'url('+id+')', 
     'background-position': '0px 0px',
      'background-size': '100% 100%',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
});
    $('#song').css('display','block');

}

var r = "res/img/";
var urls = [ r + "15.png" ];

var id = $(this).attr(urls);
```

I want to the r var add it with the url var for the full link and then add it to the attr src and then add it to the background image url.
So what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var r = "res/img/";
var urls = r + "15.png";
$('img').attr('src',urls);
doStuff2(urls);

function doStuff2(urls) {
      $("#song").css({ 
     'background-image': 'url('+urls +')', 
     'background-position': '0px 0px',
      'background-size': '100% 100%',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      'display':'block'
      });
}
```